# Android Wifi Direct Service Discovery

Tags: android, android-wifi, bonjour, wifi-direct

I'm trying to implement a simple android application that broadcasts a WifiP2p bonjour service on one device and have a second device discover and connect to it.  I've pretty much followed the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html).

I have a valid `Channel` object, a `DnsSdServiceResponseListener`, and a `DnsSdTxtRecordListener`, and set them via this call:

```
mManager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel, servListener, txtListener);
```

As of right now both listeners just spit out some debugging info to keep it real simple.

The problem is that my `DnsSdServiceResponseListener` is never called, but the `DnsSdTxtRecordListener` *does get called* and all the arguments passed in look legit.  How can one be called but not the other?

I am testing using two actual devices, both running android 4.2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally figured it out.. kind of.  When getting an instance of a service request, I was specifying the service instance name and type to match the values used when creating the service...

Registering the service:
`mServiceInfo = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(Consts.SERVICE_INSTANCE, Consts.SERVICE_REG_TYPE, record);`

Creating the service request:
`mServiceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance(Consts.SERVICE_INSTANCE, Consts.SERVICE_REG_TYPE);`

I removed the arguments to the newInstance method when getting the service request...
`mServiceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();`

and both listeners are being called now.  It seems like my first method would filter out other services being broadcasted nearby, which is why I originally opted for that overload.

Comment: Time saved. I am stucking in same problem. Thank you